# Excel: why doesn't "File-> Save As" remember the last directory that you saved a file in

Tags: microsoft-excel, save-as

i have to save about 1000 different csv files and every time i click file save as, it goes to some default directory.

is there anyway it can default to remember the directory that i saved the last file into?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try adding registry setting for Excel.

- start regedit
- go to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Excel\Options` (12.0 for Excel 2007, if you have older version of Excel it will be different, 11.0 for 2003, 10.0 for 2002...)
- add a dword value named `AlwaysSaveToCurrentPath` and set it to 0

This should make "Save As" use the same folder where the file was opened in. If you set the value to 1, it will use Default folder when using "Save As"