# Any commands to tell File Dialog windows to go to current file folder?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I get really annoyed by the fact that very often applications on windows do not default file dialog windows to the current file folder. If I am working with a file and want to save my changes under a different name or export to different format in the same folder I usually end up having to navigate to the current folder again in the file dialog. I have trained myself over the years to keep folder windows open when working to be able to copy paths back into the file dialogs to get to the current file folder.

I noticed though that you can can use commands like '..' to move up a level in the dialog, '\' to move to drive root, and use wildcards to narrow down files listed 'test*'. Are there any other helpful tricks like this and any that would be relative to the current file folder path?

Comment: you may check this tip for Excel: http://superuser.com/questions/64263/excel-why-doesnt-file-save-as-remember-the-last-directory-that-you-saved-a

Answer (score 1):

This solution does not default to open folder (I tend to have many at a time, which one would it choose), but it might get you half-way there.

Here is a document detailing where various Office programs default to and how to change them. I do all of my work on a mapped drive connected to our server, so having Office products default to My Documents drives me nuts. 
https://www.salisbury.edu/helpdesk/doc/Computer/Software/Software_MicrosoftOffice2013DefaultFileLocations.pdf

For similar instruction for older versions of Office: 
http://www.askvg.com/how-to-change-default-file-save-location-in-microsoft-office/

Hope that at least saves you a few clicks.